# Google+ share breaks using WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-activity

In an Android app, I wish to use the Google+ share API, which you invoke by navigating to:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=...
```

If my app starts an Activity like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(theUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

then a browser is created, and I see my post in Google+.

On the other hand, if I try to create an Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(theUrl);
intent.setClass(this,GoogleActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where GoogleActivity is an Activity whose onCreate() instantiates 
a WebView, and that WebView loads the url passed via the intent, 
things don't work. I see the WebView, which goes to a page allowing 
me to share the url mentioned. I can click on the Share button 
in Google+, then see my Google+ stream, just as I do when firing up 
the browser. But I don't see my shared link in my stream!

Why would these two cases be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue had nothing to do with WebView.

My Android browser was logged into Google using one account, and WebView was using another. D'oh.

WebView works perfectly for the account that it uses.